# How to display the terminal in 'Zen Mode' in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use VS Code in normal mode with an open terminal, and then I switch to `Zen Mode`, the terminal is hidden.

How to display the terminal in 'Zen Mode'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run command `View: Toggle Terminal`.

You can also use the direct keybinding for the command, the default should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's right to solved my question.

Comment: Thank you! Please accept my answer if it was the correct solution.